# What dataset to work on when Azure role is in staging deployment?

Tags: testing, deployment, azure, cloud, staging

AFAIK staging deployments are intended for testing Azure roles which implies that I could deploy a role with errors in code into staging. If that error damages my data I could be screwed.

How do I address that? I can't stage a role without reasonable data (hard to test it) and I can't let an unstable role damage the data.

Do I have to maintain a separate dataset for staging? How is this problem typically solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AFAIK staging deployments are intended for testing Azure roles which implies that I could deploy a role with errors in code into staging. If that error damages my data I could be screwed.

Staging is really designed to be a place for deployment - for spinning up new role instances prior to the instant virtual IP address swap. While you can do some testing there - e.g. making some final checks that your deployment is valid - it's not really there to allow you to do lots of testing.

> How do I address that? I can't stage a role without reasonable data (hard to test it) and I can't let an unstable role damage the data.

I've generally tested on a development environment with fake data or deployed as a separate Azure service with fake data. However, I admit this has never been in the situation where I've needed huge amounts of data for testing - generally these tests have been test deployments with just 1 or 2 users.

Answer (score 1):

Staging, as an environmentis meant to acurately simulate your production environment, **including the data**.

We have the following strategy: production is production, staging is connected to the same DB as staging, because the updates in Azure work the way they do; meaning I want to be able to upgrade my staging deployment, give the client a chance to verify again, and then swap the VIPs for the deployments, thus transitioning the application seamlessly. For those times, when there are *breaking changes* in the database, we decided to either create a new deployment alltogether, or turn-off the production one, giving users a maintenance notice.

Ultimately it's whatever you decide. But again, bearing in mind what Azure's staging is, I'd suggest keeping the data real, and consider it a beta access "program". Unless of course you have other requirements. But that's besides the point.